# default template argument VS. default function argument

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, compile-time

- **[Q0]** The main question is: what is the difference between *default template argument* and *default function argument* as they allow us to do the same things?
- **[Q1]** Does should I prefer *default template argument* when work just with compile time variables, because as it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889268/18944269) it will always provide me a compile time evaluation?

I have some code to provide you examples. [[FULL CODE]](https://godbolt.org/z/a3EzoTEzb)

- **[E1]** Struct/Class case

```cpp
template <typename val_ty, int t_size = 50>
struct buffer_a {
    using value_type = val_ty;


    buffer_a() : space(value_type{}, t_size) {}

    constexpr int size() const { return t_size; }


    std::vector<value_type> space;
};
```

```cpp
template <typename val_ty>
struct buffer_b {
    using value_type = val_ty;


    buffer_b (int t_size = 50) : space(t_size, value_type{}) {}

    constexpr int size() const { return space.size(); }


    std::vector<value_type> space;
};
```

```cpp
    // [CASE 1]: compile time buffer size
    buffer_a<double> buff_a;
    buffer_b<double> buff_b;

    coutn(buff_a.size()); // ---> 50
    coutn(buff_b.size()); // ---> 50


    // [CASE 2]: run time buffer size
    int run_time_size = 0; std::cin >> run_time_size;

    // buffer_a<int, run_time_size> buff_aa;
    //               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // ERROR: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    buffer_b<int> buff_bb(run_time_size);

    // cout(buff_aa.size());
    coutn(buff_bb.size()); // ---> $(run_time_size)
```

- **[E2]** Function case

```cpp
// [F1]
template <typename val_ty, int t_size = 50>
std::vector<val_ty> release_vector_a() {
    std::cout << "A: vector has been created\n";
    return std::vector<val_ty>(t_size, val_ty{});
}

// [F2]
template <typename val_ty>
std::vector<val_ty> release_vector_b (int size = 100) {
    std::cout << "B: vector has been created\n";
    return std::vector<val_ty>(size, val_ty{});
}

// [F3]
template <int t_size = 50>
std::vector<int> release_int_vector_a() {
    std::cout << "A<int>: vector has been created\n";
    return std::vector<int>(t_size);
}

// [F4]
std::vector<int> release_int_vector_b (int size = 100) {
    std::cout << "B<int>: vector has been created\n";
    return std::vector<int>(size);
}
```

```cpp
    // [CASE 3]: related to [CASE 1]
    release_vector_a<int>(); // compile time evaluation, because template<>, does it?
    release_vector_b<int>(); // compile time evaluation, because template<>, does it?


    // [CASE 4]
    release_int_vector_a(); // compile time evaluation, because template<>!
    release_int_vector_b(); // no compile time evaluation, no template<> and no constexpr!
```

Thanks to community!

Comment: [Q0] They also allow you to do *different* things. A function parameter can be passed at runtime, with a value not known at compile time .

Comment: A template is a pattern for generating code. A function is code. They do different things.

Comment: @PeteBecker, It seems to me that this is rather an ideological difference, because at instantiation time, code is generated for each template instantiation used in code and it just looks like a function with specified args.

Comment: @BoP, yes, you're right. I was trying to show this in [CASE 2] when I passed a runtime value as a template argument.

Comment: If you never change the value, you have a third option with `constexpr int fixed_size = 50;`, and not pass it as a parameter at all. As usual, it depends. And the fact that two features happens to be useful for the same thing is sometimes just a coincidence, like that `short` and `long` variables can both hold the value `5`. They are just different in *other* ways.

Comment: In your E1 code, as `space` is public, we might change it. So `buffer_a::size()` might differ than `buffer_a::space::size()`. (as size is compile-time constant `std::array` would be more appropriate BTW).

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks, good point. Also, starting with `C++20` `std::vector.size()` is [also](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) marked as `constexpr` and in this regard there is no difference between `std::array.size()` and `std::vector.size()`. But if we work with a C++ standard under the `C++20` your variant is better

Comment: Even in C++20, you cannot have `constexpr std::vector<T>`...